# Print out a list of all cases of a switch

Tags: bash

Curious question. Is it somehow possible to print out all cases of a certain switch-case **automatically** in bash? In a way, such that it stays as maintainable as possible, meaning that one does not have to add any more code if a new case is added to print out that same case.

For instance, that would be useful if the cases represented commands. A help function could then print out all available commands.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built-in function for this. You'd have to process the shell script as text (by passing $0 to a function along with the call site information), which is certainly possible in bash, but it's not going to be easy...

Comment: To do that *properly*, you'd have to parse the shell script up until the call site. That's not something I'd do in bash, I'd do that in C. And someone **must** have done that before, I just can't find anything like it right now...

Comment: you could mark the start and end of each switch with a unique code in a comment (pragma), that you also pass on to a perl/awk script (along with $0).  That would already become.... feasible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve this, but you can use an *array* to maintain your choices:

```
# Define your choices - be sure not to change their order later; only
# *append* new ones.
choices=( foo bar baz )

# Make the array elements the case branches *in order*.
case "$1" in
    "${choices[0]}")
        echo 'do foo'
        ;;

    "${choices[1]}")
        echo 'do bar'
        ;;

    "${choices[2]}")
        echo 'do baz'
        ;;

    *)
        echo "All choices: ${choices[@]}"

esac
```

This makes the branches less readable, but it's a manageable solution, if you maintain your array carefully.

Note how the branch conditions are enclosed in `"..."` so as to prevent the shell from interpreting the values as (glob-like) *patterns*.

That said, as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out, perhaps you *want to* define your choices as *patterns* to match variations of a string:

In that event:

- *Define* the pattern *with quotes* in the `choices` array; e.g., `choices=( foo bar baz 'h*' )`
- *Reference* it *unquoted* in the `case` branch; e.g., `${choices[3]})`

Answer (score 3):

`bash` does not give you access to the tokens it parses and does not save `case` strings (which can be glob expressions as well).

Unfortunately, that means you will not be able to DRY your code in the way you were hoping.

Answer (score 1):

After a while of hacking together several Bash 4 features I've got this one.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail 

# create coprocess with 2 descriptors so we can read and write to them
coproc CAT { cat ; }

# creme de la creme of this solution - use function to both collect and select elements
function element {
    echo "$1" >&${CAT[1]}
    echo "$1"
}   

case "$1" in
    $(element A))
            echo "Your choice is: A"
    ;;

    $(element B))
            echo "Your choice is: B"
    ;;

    *)
            echo "Your choice is not present in available options: $1"
            # close writing descriptor
            exec {CAT[1]}>&-
            #read colected options into an array
            mapfile -t OPTIONS <&${CAT[0]}

            echo "Available options are: [ ${OPTIONS[@]} ]"

    ;;
esac
```

Output:

```
Your choice is not present in available options: C
Available options are: [ A B ]
```

There are 2 parts for this solution:

- `coproc` - which creates subprocess for reading and writing from subshell
- function `element` which both writes into descriptors of `coproc` subrocess and returns it's argument so we can use it inside `case ... esac`

If handling all options should be done outside of `case` then you can use `;;&` feature of Bash 4 `case` statement which forces checking *every* statement inside `case` (usually - i.e. `;;` - it stops after first match). This checking is needed so we can collect all options into an array later

There is probably a lot of reasons not to use this (limits of data which can be safely stored in descriptor without reading them being one of those) and I welcome all comments which can make this solution better.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your script inspect itself:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

case_start=$(("$LINENO" + 2))       #store line number of start
case "$1" in

    simple_case) echo "this is easy";;
    --tricky)
        echo "This is a tricky"
        (echo "Multiline")
        echo "Statement"
        ;;
    -h|--help) echo "heeeelp me";;
    -q|--quiet) ;;

    *) echo "unknown option";;
esac
case_end=$(("$LINENO" - 2))         #store line number of end

# - take lines between $case_start and $case_end
# - replace newlines with spaces
# - replace ";;" with newlines
# -=> now every case statement should be on its own line
# - then filter out cases: delete everything after the first ")" including the ")" and trim blanks
cases_available=`sed -n "${case_start},${case_end}p" $0 | sed 's/#.*//' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/;;/\n/g' | sed 's/).*//;s/[[:blank:]]*//'`

echo -e "cases_available:\n\n$cases_available"
```

this would print:

```
cases_available:
 
simple_case
--tricky
-h|--help
-q|--quiet
*
```

There are some pitfalls with this:

- Comments or strings inside the case statement with a ";;" in it will break stuff
- Can't handle nested switch case statements.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if I understood correctly your question, but you can do something like [this page says](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) to print out all the available cases as default choice:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;

    stop)
        stop
        ;;

    status)
        status anacron
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    condrestart)
        if test "x`pidof anacron`" != x; then
            stop
            start
        fi
        ;;

    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
        exit 1

esac
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to have some kind of function `listAllCases` (which autonomously goes through all cases of a switch) and use it like this: `*) listAllCases`.

Comment: In all the languages i know is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach and also in OP regards is to actually print the switch case structure to a new file and then source it in the original file if needed.

```sh
echo "case "'"$1"'" in" > case.sh
echo "  test)" >> case.sh
echo "    echo "This case!"" >> case.sh
echo "    ;;" >> case.sh
echo "esac" >> case.sh

chmod+x case.sh

./case.sh test

#This case!
```

This way you can easily use variables to build your switch / case condition.